# How can I localize PWA camera strings in Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using the *Capacitor* camera plugin to get a user's photos.

The code is here:

```
const { Camera } = Plugins;
Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 90,
      allowEditing: false,
      resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
      source: CameraSource.Prompt,
      saveToGallery: false,
    })....
```

How can I translate Camera strings like below image? (No camera found, Choose image.)

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "camera strings" and what do you mean by translating those strings ?

Comment: I do not see this message in the source code of capacitor camera plugins. Can you mention your platform, package version

Comment: @CCBet, @YousafRaza: the OP means the two strings which you can see on the screenshot: "No camera found" and "Choose image". These strings appear when `Camera.getPhoto` is called with no camera available — e.g. on Windows platform if the camera is missing or the device is deactivated. This is still valid for the latest versions of Ionic/Capacitor. Translating the strings means replacing them with custom values via some configuration — something like [`promptLabelPhoto`/`promptLabelPicture` config settings of the Capacitor Camera plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/camera).

Comment: Ok, I get it. Ionic PWA elements uses stencil js and the message for no camera found is the input to the web element that exists in `ionic-team/pwa-elements` repo. If you can get the reference to the ionic's `PWA-element`, just give it the custom input of `noDevicesText` and it will be as you want. I know it's a hack but there is no direct input given for this usecase. You can also create a feature request to the camera plugin repo

Comment: See: https://github.com/ionic-team/pwa-elements/blob/master/src/components/camera/camera.tsx

Comment: Thanks @YousafRaza. Maybe you could post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic [PWA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_application) elements uses [Stencil](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil) and the message for no camera found is the input to the web element that exists in the `ionic-team/pwa-elements` repository.

If you can get the reference to the Ionic's PWA-element, just give it the custom input of `noDevicesText` and it will be as you want. I know it's a hack, but there isn’t any direct input given for this use case. You can also create a feature request to the camera plugin repository.

***See*** *[camera.tsx](https://github.com/ionic-team/pwa-elements/blob/master/src/components/camera/camera.tsx)*.

E.g.:

```
// pwa-camera is the PWA camera component
let cameraElement = document.querySelector('pwa-camera');
if (cameraElement) {
  cameraElement.noDevicesText = this.someService.translate(message);
}
```